# VSCode Start Debugging

Tags: python, macos, vscode-debugger

I am currently using Python in VSCode on a Mac and whenever I click 'Start Debugging' or 'Run Without Debugging' this image appears [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF9ef.png) and I don't know what to do to start debugging. This is my launch.Json file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipXqA.png). Am I doing something wrong?